# Spyder: Disable copying when nothing is selected

Tags: spyder

In Spyder, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will overwrite the previously copied even when the selection is empty, unlike most other applications (apparently Atom and Sublime Text also do this). It frequently happens that I want to paste with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, and hit copy instead, which is an annoying waste of time.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Sidenote: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> doesn't overwrite when nothing is selected, so Spyder isn't consistent there.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is the behavior of most applications, i.e. they replace the previously copied text with your new selection. I don't see how we could avoid that, other than maintaining a list of previously copied text so you can go back and select an entry on it.

However, that's something other applications are specifically designed to do (e.g. Klipper on Linux), so you should be better by installing any of them. Their generic name is *Clipboard managers*.